# Displaying Django templates in a VueJS template

Tags: django, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following django index page:

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/3.8.95/css/materialdesignicons.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My test</title>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="app">
     <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>

    {% render_bundle 'main' %}

</body>
</html>
```

This template is supposed to call my VueJS frontend, so that i can use Vue on my Django templates, this is the Vue template being called:

```
<template>

  <v-app id="sandbox">
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="primaryDrawer.model"
      :clipped="primaryDrawer.clipped"
      :floating="primaryDrawer.floating"
      :mini-variant="primaryDrawer.mini"
      :permanent="primaryDrawer.type === 'permanent'"
      :temporary="primaryDrawer.type === 'temporary'"
      app
      overflow
    ><v-switch
        v-model="$vuetify.theme.dark"
        primary
        label="Dark"
      ></v-switch></v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-app-bar
      :clipped-left="primaryDrawer.clipped"
      app
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon
        v-if="primaryDrawer.type !== 'permanent'"
        @click.stop="primaryDrawer.model = !primaryDrawer.model"
      ></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Vuetify</v-toolbar-title>

    </v-app-bar>


    </v-app>
</template>
```

Which is just a simple Vuetify default template, really similar to [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/examples/layouts/sandbox).

Until now, it's alright, i can see the page but i don't see the Django part in my template. To debug it, i added that `<h1> TEST </h1>` to my index page, so when i open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` i should see the Vue template + the Django template.

The problem is that i don't see the `<h1>`. I think that somehow the Vue/Vuetify components are hiding it, because if i remove everything from the Vue part, except `<template></template>` i will see the `<h1>TEST</h1>` appearing.

I need to fix this issue, since, of course, i'll need to display my django part alongside with the Vue part. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

When you use Vue's el selector, you're basically telling to go and find that selector and replace it with your template. So the `<div id="app">` and everything inside it is being replaced with your Vue component. If you want your Django static to be rendered, simply move it outside of the Vue div.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that even if it's outside the Vue template, i won't see it